# Can a report be built in Access where users select the fields they want then create said report?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an Access database which I have restricted for end users as I do not want them interfering with tables, queries and the like.

Is it possible to develop a tool so that users can select the fields they want to include in a report and then produce said report themselves?

Effectively, I mostly want to replicate the Query Builder function in Access because users do not have access to this due to the (necessary) system restrictions that I have put in place.

Ideally, this is how it will work.  End users will:

- Open `Report` function and are presented with a list of tables
- Choose required fields.
- Add criteria.
- Run report.

Can this be / has something like this been done?  Does anyone have any examples of such a feature?

Comment: I did something very similar years ago and it still scares me silly.

Comment: @Fionnuala Is it something you now regret?

Comment: Pretty much. Editing the code is almost impossible.

Comment: I should add that the output was fully formatted in HTML. With colours and so forth.

Comment: I see. At present, end users come to me with requests for reports and I then build them and give them access. I have built a search feature, where users enter criteria which dynamically creates a query string and then executes that, producing results below the form. The difference with this compared to my question is that users cannot choose which fields to include - I determined that from the onset and that won't change. I want to give my users more flexibility around which fields they choose to query, hence the question.

Comment: How many fields? Consider listboxes.

Comment: Fully-formatted HTML? Wow. If you mean how many fields I want to offer my users, then the answer is all of them; I basically want to show them the contents of each table and then they can pick and choose as many fields as they wish (effectively replicating the `Query Builder` function in MS Access). Although I should mention that I want to restrict them to only querying one table at a time to prevent errors (and save a whole bunch of coding).

Comment: In most of cases such kind requests from users can be satisfied if you create few exports to Excel with maximum required columns. Users will be able to make their own "reports" in Excel with source data from exports. Try to talk to them.

Comment: @SergeyS. In fact, the search feature that I mentioned earlier allows users to export all relevant data to Excel, including data from all fields.  I have explained to one particular user countless times how this is the way to go about it, but they simply don't understand so thought I'd check to see if there was a potential way (however complicated) in order to stop them from nagging. Not to worry, I will advise them of this alternative (better) method. Thank you all.